# Carousel Width Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some problems with my JCarouselLite. It scrolls some images for me, and works very well in a big screen, but for some reason it only scrolls within the confines of the browser size, rather than just scrolling within the confines of whatever width you set it.

My URL is [www.peach-designs.com](http://www.peach-designs.com) ...whatever size screen you have, if you restore your screen to half the size, then use the right/left scrollbar to move across, you get a huge white space, which makes the site look very strange.

Hope you can help,

Kind Regards,

Snakespan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on csss

```
html,body {overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: Hi, that doesn't quite work, as when I view it on a person's computer with a small screen, I can't scroll down to click anything in the nav bar.

Comment: well the width of ur `#navbar` is like `2000px` and you hiding the scroll bars of the body tag. either that, or put another wrapper to wrap the wrap and nav bar together give it a css width of 100% and overflow:hidden

Comment: great thank you very much, I appreciate your comments, it seemed to work after, without the overflow: hidden attribute.